# Why and I getting: "Invalid regular expression. Uncaught SyntaxError. Invalid escape."?

Tags: regex, syntax-error

Im trying to create an html input tag that accepts only numbers entered in 1 of 2 formats, and reject all other input.

I want to accept numbers in these formats only, including requiring the dashes:

```
1234-12
```

and

```
1234-12-12
```

**note:** this is not for dates, but rather legal chapter numbers

Everything I am reading about regex says that the following should work, but it isn't.

```
<input class="form-control"
                       type="text"
                       pattern="^(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})|(\d{4}\-\d{2})$"
                       required />
```

Devtools Console Error in Chrome:

> Pattern attribute value `^(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})|(\d{4}\-\d{2})$` is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})|(\d{4}-\d{2})$/: Invalid escape

Comment: Replace `\-` with `-`.

Comment: You're getting "invalid escape" because you have an invalid escape in your regex. Outside of a character class (`[]`), `-` has no special meaning. So `\-` is an invalid escape.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I think the confusing part here is that `/\-/` is a legal regex in JS, while `/\-/u` is not. Usually (i.e. almost everywhere) identity escapes are not an error, but permitted, even though strictly not necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not escape the hyphen *outside a character class in ES6 regex* used with the `u` flag (the one used by default in `pattern` regexps in the current versions of Chrome and FF).

Also, the regex in the pattern attribute is anchored by default, remove the redudant `^` and `$` and shorten the pattern by using an optional group

```
pattern="\d{4}-\d{2}(-\d{2})?"
```

This regex in the HTML5 `pattern` attribute means:

- `\d{4}-\d{2}` - match 4 digits, `-`, and then 2 digits from the start of string
- `(-\d{2})?` - and optionally match a `-` and then 2 digits at the end of the string.

Comment: I added the clarification: inside the character class, the hyphen can be escaped even in ES6 regex with `u` modifier since inside a character class, `-` may have a special meaning.

Comment: Oh yes, absolutely, I was not aware of that before. Thank you again!