# Regex invalid escape

Tags: regex

Can someone help me with this following regex? I tested in on few sites and said it was OK, but my element inspector tells me that there is an invalid escape

```
 ([0-9]{4})+\-?([0-9]{4})+\-?([0-9]{4})+\-?([0-9]{4})
```

It will produce this pattern (credit card format)

```
 1234-1234-1234-1234
```

A person does not have to include a dash when inputting the number

Thank you

Comment: You don't need to escape `-` in a regular expression, except inside `[]`.

Comment: Is it javascript or php ? Please make your mind before tagging and tell us how you use this regex.

Comment: Your expression works for both [javascript](https://regex101.com/r/TT9roY/1) and [php](https://regex101.com/r/TT9roY/1) - so what is your question really?

Comment: You don't need the `+` between the segments either

Comment: See [Why and I getting: “Invalid regular expression. Uncaught SyntaxError. Invalid escape.”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40723751)

Answer (score 1):

Removed unnecessary/invalid escaping of `-`. Removed `+`es after digit groups.

```
([0-9]{4})-?([0-9]{4})-?([0-9]{4})-?([0-9]{4})
```

or using the `\d` metacharacter

```
(\d{4})-?(\d{4})-?(\d{4})-?(\d{4})
```

Comment: Keep on: remove the groups.

Comment: It depends if he wants to capture the input or just validate it.

Comment: Why do you think the error appears? It is used in the `pattern` attribute. There is no extracting going on there. I highly doubt OP is using `/u` modifier explicitly.

Comment: I get your point, but the question's only tag is `regex`, which means that this answer could work for people looking to capture credit card information in any environment, not only browsers. Don't forget about those poor bastards ;-)